# GetParameterAsText if statement

Tags: arcpy, parameters

In the code below the user picks from one of the following "GetParameterAsText" values:

Tampa, Orlando, Denver, Cosprings

```
# Variables/Parameters
market = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
nfid_fqn_associations = "G:\\Project_Verizon_" + **market** + "\\02GISData\\VZ3GIS\\SHP Workspace"
workspace = "G:\\Project_Verizon_" + **market** + "\\02GISData\\VZ3GIS\\File Workspace"

# Create table
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(nfid_fqn_associations, workspace, "SHP_Report", "Where Clause")
```

How do I make it so if they select Tampa as their input variable it inserts the value "57" into the arcpy.TableToTable_conversion() "Where Clause"?

**Associated integer:**

```
Tampa : 57

Orlando : 1

Denver : 45
```

Here's how I'd attempt:

```
# Variables/Parameters
market = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
value = 0
if market == "Tampa":
    value = 57
if market == "Denver":
    value = 45

# Create table
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(nfid_fqn_associations, workspace, "SHP_Report", "MARKETID = " + "'" + value + "'")
```

This script will be turned into a geoprocessing tool so I'm not entirely sure how to take the users input and initialize the variable "value" based off the associated integer above.

Comment: It appears that you want to use a Python dictionary.  While an `if` could work, it would have to be used correctly (case and quoted), and the solution just *begs* for a dictionary lookup.

Comment: @Vince This script will be turned into a geoprocessing tool so I'm not entirely sure how to take the users input and initialize the variable "value" based off the associated integer above. I need to get two pieces of information from the user by them entering one as shown above.

Comment: Go ahead and research dictionaries in the Python language. You should also add error checking and possibly case independence, but that's basic coding.